# Powershell Get-FileMetaData not recognized

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I am trying to use the PowerShell command 'Get-FileMetaData' however PowerShell ISE outputs the following error:

```
Get-FileMetaData : The term 'Get-FileMetaData' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path 
was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-FileMetaData E:\Test_Output
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-FileMetaData:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

The path is correct, I have also tried various existing paths. I cant find anything about what version this command requires, but using `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion` output states 'Major 5' so I believe I am using PS v5.

Has anyone else had issue with this command? I have found various forums mentioning its function, but cant find much on troubleshooting it.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not a core PowerShell cmdlet so I would expect that to fail for most people. As far as I know that comes from the <strike>[Script Gallery](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-FileMetaData-3a7ddea7)</strike> [GitHub](https://gist.github.com/woehrl01/5f50cb311f3ec711f6c776b2cb09c34e). You need to download that first.

So if you want that to be loaded then take that module will need to be imported either manually or automatically.

[You can read more about module loading on learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/module/importing-a-powershell-module?view=powershell-7.3)

Comment: Thanks @Matt, any idea of the best way to pull meta data utilizing standard cmdlets? I am looking to assign a files 'Author' as a variable.

Comment: @Garrett what type of file is this which has an author attribute?

Comment: @FoxDeploy it will be a jpg.

Comment: @Garrett Get-FileMetaData is not officially a cmdlet but a custom function. Nothing stopping you from using it anywhere you want. To really answer your question I am not aware of any core PowerShell functionality that would do this for you. Still better than relying on external exes though.

Comment: Both links dead now. Have not found an equivalent.

Comment: apparently the script can be found here: https://gist.github.com/woehrl01/5f50cb311f3ec711f6c776b2cb09c34e

Answer (score 0):

Using the free tool 'exiftool' I have put together to following script:

```
$creator = C:\Windows\exiftool.exe "-Creator" $Image.FullName
```

This allows `$creator` to be the files Creator which in the case of our production images is the same as the Author.