# "Get-FileMetaData" not Cmdlet in Powershell

Tags: powershell

i get following error:

```
Get-FileMetaData : Die Benennung "Get-FileMetaData" wurde nicht als Name eines Cmdlet, einer Funktion, einer 
Skriptdatei oder eines ausführbaren Programms erkannt. Überprüfen Sie die Schreibweise des Namens, oder ob 
der Pfad korrekt ist (sofern enthalten), und wiederholen Sie den Vorgang.
In D:\Neuer Ordner\Sort.ps1:21 Zeichen:14
+ $picMeaData= Get-FileMetaData -folder (Get-ChildItem D:xxxx
+              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-FileMetaData:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

my code looks like:

```
$picMeaData= Get-FileMetaData -folder (Get-ChildItem D:\xxx -Recurse -Directory ).FullName

$picMeaData
```

i think i have to install a extra module that contains the "get-fileMetaData". i dont know if i install it the right way. is following correct, or do i have to make other steps?

```
Get-PSRepository

Register-PSRepository -Default
```

does this work ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Powershell Get-FileMetaData not recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47288588/powershell-get-filemetadata-not-recognized)

Comment: @JeffZeitlin i also saw this, but there is not a answer that solve my problem

Comment: @JeffZeitlin i dont know how i can download the script gallery,thats why im asking

Comment: Try from [here](https://gist.github.com/woehrl01/5f50cb311f3ec711f6c776b2cb09c34e). Download the module to the modules path and use `Import-Module` as first line in your code. Or just copy the function and place that in your code on top

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the repository registered, you can use `Find-Module -Command 'Get-FileMetaData'` to see which module(s) provide a function with that name. For example:

```
Find-Module -Command 'Get-FileMetaData'

Version      Name                  Repository   Description                                        
-------      ----                  ----------   -----------                                        
0.0.207      PSSharedGoods         PSGallery    Module covering functions that are shared within...
5.0.0        FC_SysAdmin           PSGallery    General sys admin functions                        
4.5.1        CPolydorou.FileSystem PSGallery    This module contains functions relative to files...
```

If the module you want is in the list, then install it once and import it at the beginning of your script to load it:

```sh
Install-Module "Name"
Import-Module "Name"
```

If you are following a guide or other sample, make sure you are using the same module.